# AES simple functions- 'int' object not iterable

Tags: python, error-handling, aes

I'm attempting to write a simple implementation of the AES in Python, not unheard of but it is for a class so I'm not looking at anyone else's documentation.

I'm getting the same issue with a few of my simplest functions - subWord and rotWord

```
def subWord(word):
    return [Sbox[byte] for byte in word]

def rotWord(word):
    temp = word[0]
    for i in range(3): 
        word[i] = word[i+1]
        word[3] = temp
    return word
```

both of which intake a simple input - I'm using the professor's test cases which are as follows

```
subWord(0x00102030) == 0x63cab704
subWord(0x40506070) == 0x0953d051
subWord(0x8090a0b0) == 0xcd60e0e7
subWord(0xc0d0e0f0) == 0xba70e18c

rotWord(0x09cf4f3c) == 0xcf4f3c09
rotWord(0x2a6c7605) == 0x6c76052a
```

but I keep receiving the same error - TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please include the full traceback. But indeed those arguments are just numbers so you can't index into `word[0]` etc. What do you think `0x1234[0]` should produce?

Comment: Try `for byte in bytes([word])`

Comment: @JohnGordon I received the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-76-ada5c8007198>", line 1, in <module>
    subWord(0xc0d0e0f0)

  File "project1\aes.py", line 66, in subWord
    return [Sbox[byte] for byte in bytes([word])]

ValueError: bytes must be in range(0, 256)

Comment: @tripleee
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-78-ada5c8007198>", line 1, in <module>
    subWord(0xc0d0e0f0)

  File "C:\Users\user\project1\aes.py", line 66, in subWord
    return [Sbox[byte] for byte in word]

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Hmm, I definitely understand that from scrolling similar questions but I'm unsure how to rectify it, my code needs to process that input, but I'm unsure the best format to process the int. Any attempts I have made to handle it as a string have given indexing errors.

Comment: Integer objects have a `.to_bytes()` function.  Perhaps you could try that?

Comment: @JohnGordon
Unfortunately I'm now getting this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-88-38b99f7b227f>", line 1, in <module>
    rotWord(0x09cf4f3c)

  File "C:\Users\user\project1\aes.py", line 73, in rotWord
    word[i] = word[i+1]

TypeError: 'bytes' object does not support item assignment